# unable to use threadpoolexecutor in a flask app run with gunicorn preload flags

Tags: python, flask, boto3, gunicorn

I have a flask app which i'm trying to front with gunicorn. I want to use the preload flag since my application has some scheduled jobs using apscheduler which i want only to run in the master and not the workers.

I also want to use the ThreadPoolExecutor in python to delegate jobs to the background triggered by a route on my app.

when I use the --preload flag with gunicorn any calls to my threadpoolexecutor (using executor.submit) seem to fail. The same seems to happen when i programatically trigger a job through the apscheduler.

When i don't use the --preload flag everything runs smoothly.

Is there some config i can change to get this working or would this not work with the --preload flag?